# how to make entry box in tkinter expand vertically as the user types text?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am wondering if there is any updated solution to "Large Tkinter entry boxes" as the ones I've tried doesn't seem to work for me.

Python: 3.6.3

Comment: The `Entry` widget can only display one line. If it expands vertically, all you get is a bunch of extra white space. Is that what you want?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Partho63 you can have a look here --> http://prntscr.com/mk7nyt
I need the entry to be expanded to the bottom as I don't have space in my original program to expand it to the left or to the right.
What I need is all the text to be visible at a time not just a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After watching the example image you gave I came up with these three solutions:

**1.** You can set the height and width of the tk window and make the **Entry** take the whole area. Here I have given the height and width of the screen.

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()

screen_width = str(r.winfo_screenwidth())
screen_height = str(r.winfo_screenheight())
r.geometry(screen_width + "x" + screen_height + "+0+0")

text = """abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n"""

e = Entry()
e.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
e.insert("0", text)

r.mainloop()
```

**2.** But Entry only shows text in one line. If want to show multiple lines then you can use **Text**. This solution is same as solution 1 only difference is using **Text** instead of **Entry**

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()

screen_width = str(r.winfo_screenwidth())
screen_height = str(r.winfo_screenheight())
r.geometry(screen_width + "x" + screen_height + "+0+0")

text = """abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n"""

t = Text(r)
t.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
t.insert("end", text)

r.mainloop()
```

**3.** Third option is you can set **Scrollbar**(horizontal/vertical). So that user can see all the text by scroling vertically/horizontally.

```
from tkinter import *

r = Tk()

text = """First: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
Second: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
Third: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n
Fourth: abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd\n"""


def onConfigure(canvas):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

c = Canvas(r, width=560, height=80)
t = Text(c, width=99, height=9)
t.insert("end", text)
hsb = Scrollbar(r, orient='horizontal', command=c.xview)
vsb = Scrollbar(r, orient='vertical', command=c.yview)
c.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
hsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='esw')
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nes')
c.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')

c.create_window((0, 0), window=t, anchor='center')
t.bind('<Configure>', lambda event, canvas=c: onConfigure(c))

r.mainloop()
```